# lightweight way to get the current user in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using some non-controller scripts to provide data for some ajax forms etc.. Doing this for performance reasons, as the controller overhead is pretty high. however, i would like to do some work based on the current user, so would like the lightest weight way to get that user..

1. i'm seeing about 100 - 150 ms response times for a controller that is doing nothing but serving a view, is that normal? my basic php script to get the data from the db, and return is only 2 - 5 ms
2. outside of a controller context, how do i get the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

Inject the `security.context` service into your service and use it:

```
$user = $this->sc->getToken()->getUser();
```

Comment: Hm, that would require it to be a service, which isn't directly callable i believe.. ie: needs to be called from a controller, is there a way to do this outside of a controller?

Comment: Everything else should be a service in symfony. Any (public) service can be called from the controller. And any service can get injected any other service. Read the [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)